# Mount EBS volume to a running AWS instance with a script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, boto3, amazon-ebs

I'd like to dynamically mount and unmount an EBS volumes to a running AWS instance using a script and was wondering whether this is achievable, both on linux and windows instances, and if so, what is the expected duration of such operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html) and Bourne shell script.

[attach-volume](http://aws%20ec2%20attach-volume%20--volume-id%20vol-1234567890abcdef0%20--instance-id%20i-01474ef662b89480%20--device%20/dev/sdf)

> Attaches an EBS volume to a running or stopped instance and exposes it
>   to the instance with the specified device name.

```
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-1234567890abcdef0 --instance-id i-01474ef662b89480 --device /dev/sdf
```

[detach-volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/detach-volume.html)

> Detaches an EBS volume from an instance. Make sure to unmount any file
>   systems on the device within your operating system before detaching
>   the volume.

```
aws ec2 detach-volume --volume-id vol-1234567890abcdef0
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------

Use Python and [Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which has APIs to attach and detach volumes.

[attach_volume](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.attach_volume)

> Attaches an EBS volume to a running or stopped instance and exposes it
>   to the instance with the specified device name.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.attach_volume(
    DryRun=True|False,
    VolumeId='string',
    InstanceId='string',
    Device='string'
)
```

[detach_volume](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.detach_volume)

> Detaches an EBS volume from an instance. Make sure to unmount any file
>   systems on the device within your operating system before detaching
>   the volume.

```
response = client.detach_volume(
    DryRun=True|False,
    VolumeId='string',
    InstanceId='string',
    Device='string',
    Force=True|False
)
```

Comment: I believe that the answer does not match the question.
The question was regarding mounting and un-mounting after attaching operation and not about the attach itself.